# Geometry Corner Mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm practising with a mesh object typical cube. Added a whole bunch of cuts in the mesh. I believed the mesh is clean with no problems, until I added the subdivision surface, and down the corner of IMG 03, suddenly it's creating a triangle and also some weird unclean artefact on the surface. That I sort of cleaned adding more loop cuts, but it didnt clean 100%. But that corner triangle I cant figure out what it can cause it.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This looks like double vertices or non-manifold faces. Are you sure there aren't any? You can also [share you .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I checked if there's double faces, but cant seem to locate any.
Ive uploaded my file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=OAlWk65M" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/OAlWk65M/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mesh has some n-gons and the *Subdivision Modifier* doesn't like it. :)
Make your mesh only from quads and it will subdivide properly.

Other little issues:

- Messed up scale - Solve through *Object > Apply > Scale* (and check normals afterwards)
- Non-manifold faces - some faces are going through another. This has to be repaired manually. Either merge the vertices, or move the faces farther away.

*Quads vs. N-gons with Subdivision Modifier*

[image]

*Apply your object's scale to avoid problems in the future.*

[image]

Here is your .blend back, repaired so you can compare :).
[image]

Comment: I cant believe that I didnt noticed the n-gons right in front of my mesh.
Thanks for your help Jacym!

https://ibb.co/g6gbSrW